# Obtener cierta cantida de valores por usuario Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, foreach

Necesito solo obtener 4 obras por artista,
esta es mi tabla de obras y tiene un id de usuario

```
id|id_usuario
1|       2
2|       2
3|       3
4|       3
5|       3
6|       4
7|       3
8|       3
9|       2
```

y solo necesito obtener 4 obras por id_usuario
, en teoría me deberia quedar asi

```
id|id_usuario
1|       2
2|       2
3|       3
4|       3
5|       3
6|       4
7|       3
9|       2
```

intente haciendo esto con mi consulta

```
$obras=  Artista::leftJoin('obras', function ($join) {
        $join->on('obras.id_usuario', '=', 'artistas.id')
        // ->take(2);
       ;
    })
    ->select('artistas.name', 'obras.*')
    ->where('status','=','enabled')
    ->take(4)
    ->get();
```

pero solo me obtiene 4 obras de toda la tabla y necesito 4 obras por id_usuarios

alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: no tengo relaciones definidas

Comment: si, estan en lo correcto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que tenemos estos 2 modelos:

- Artista
- Obra

Podemos constituir una consulta auxiliádonos de las [*relaciones de Eloquent*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) del modo siguiente:

```
    Artista::with(['obras' => function($query) {
        $query->take(4);
    }])->get();
```

Lo que hicimos fue:

- En el modelo `Artista` declaramos el siguiente método:

  ```
  public function obras()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(Obra::class);
  }
  ```
- Dentro de la consulta usamos el método `with` para apoyarnos de [*eager loading*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) para cargar de forma *ambiciosa* todas las obras relacionadas que tiene el modelo `Artista`

  ```
  Artista::with('obras')
  ```
- Como necesitamos limitar la cantidad de obras por cada artista, entonces dentro del método `with` pasamos un *array asociativo* donde la clave es la relación y el valor es una función que nos ayudará a constituir una consulta extra:

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió de mucho